# Android App Crashing Depending on how Array of Objects is declared?

Tags: android, arrays, listadapter

Thanks for reading this and helping out! I really appreciate it. On one of my activities in my app I have a list view, Which is supposed to display an array of custom type "MemberListObject" I also have a custom MemberListObjectAdapter class. The code works great when I delcare the array as such(In my OnCreate method). The list displays exactly how I want it too

```
MemberListObject[] memberListObject_data = new MemberListObject[]{
    new MemberListObject(R.drawable.icon_pin,"Chocolate")
};
MemberListObjectAdapter adapter = new MemberListObjectAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.listview_item_row, memberListObject_data);
listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

However when I delcare my array like this

```
MemberListObject[] memberListObject_data= new MemberListObject[5];
 memberListObject_data[0].icon=(R.drawable.icon_pin); 
 memberListObject_data[0].title="Chocolate";
 MemberListObjectAdapter adapter = new MemberListObjectAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.listview_item_row, memberListObject_data);
listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

my app crashes when the activity is ran, this has been confusing me for a while.

here is my "MemberListObjectAdapter.java"

```
public class MemberListObjectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MemberListObject>{

Context context; 
int layoutResourceId;    
MemberListObject data[] = null;

public MemberListObjectAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, MemberListObject[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    WeatherHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new WeatherHolder();
        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    MemberListObject memberListObject = data[position];
    holder.txtTitle.setText(memberListObject.title);
    holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(memberListObject.icon);

    return row;
}

static class WeatherHolder
{
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
}
}
```

So My question is, why might my app be crashing when I declare/use it the 2nd way but not the first way? Thanks alot!

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: njzk2, I could have sworn I tried that, but that fixed my issue for now thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you create an array, the members are not created automatically. You have to do that yourself.

```
MemberListObject[] memberListObject_data= new MemberListObject[5];
memberListObject_data[0] = new MemberListObject();
memberListObject_data[1] = new MemberListObject();
memberListObject_data[2] = new MemberListObject();
memberListObject_data[3] = new MemberListObject();
memberListObject_data[4] = new MemberListObject();
```

or with a loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < memberListObject_data.length; i++){
    memberListObject_data[i] = new MemberListObject();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so quick, I forgot to mention I also tried that using this "MemberListObject[] memberListObject_data= new MemberListObject[5];
memberListObject_data[0] = new MemberListObject(R.drawable.icon_phikeia,"Chocolate");"

Comment: Well of course you have to initialize all five objects, not just the first one. Are you getting the same exception if you do that? Post the exception stacktrace, without it's hard to know what's going on.